# How to achieve 2 servers to communicate over HTTPS and IP addresses

Tags: linux, ip, https

I am not an expert in this topic and so did a lot of research but could not find a clear anwser that I could understand.

I have 2 webapps (microservices) on 2 servers/machines. The webapps communicate with each other over http requests.

I would like to let them communicate using HTTPS (I think that whould be more secure).

The problem is, I use IP addresses of those 2 servers for communication, they have no domains. And I would not like to bind them to any domain, because their communication is just 'private', between them.

If I understood well, to enable HTTPS communication I need a certificate, but certificates are only possible for domains (or IPs that I own, but in my case the host is the owner of the IPs).

Am I doing/understanding something wrong? What should be the solution?

I appreciate your suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Configure self signed certificates, and configure your application to trust the certificate
2. Set up DNS and use e.g. Lets Encrypt certificates to secure the communication.

The security is more or less the same in both scenarios. Your communication is not private just because you don't use DNS. The complete IPv4 address space is regularly scanned.

Comment: Thanks. You helped me. Especially your advice that an IP not using DNS is not more private.

Comment: Rely on authentication to ensure secrecy. Trying to be obscure on the Internet doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can still generate self-signed certificates with your host names. Then you can configure your services to trust the self-signed certificates of the other server.